# How to parse the response received from soap webservice

Tags: android, ksoap2

I want to retrieve values stored in remote server through webservice.I am getting a response but not able to parse it.

Here is the response i am getting

```
anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }
```

and also

```
anyType{DocumentElement=anyType{Table=anyType{MST_BloodGroupID=1; BloodGroup_Name=A+; }; Table=anyType{MST_BloodGroupID=2; BloodGroup_Name=A-; }; Table=anyType{MST_BloodGroupID=3; BloodGroup_Name=B+; }; Table=anyType{MST_BloodGroupID=4; BloodGroup_Name=B-; }; Table=anyType{MST_BloodGroupID=5; BloodGroup_Name=AB+; }; Table=anyType{MST_BloodGroupID=6; BloodGroup_Name=AB-; }; Table=anyType{MST_BloodGroupID=7; BloodGroup_Name=O+; }; Table=anyType{MST_BloodGroupID=8; BloodGroup_Name=O-; }; }; }
```

I want to retrive blood group id's from above responce.Please can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

please give me fast reply.

Comment: Which language? Please add the relevant language tag.

Comment: i added relevant tag

Answer (score 0):

there is a third party library that can handle parsing ksoap notation: https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/